# viewDidAppear called before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate, viewdidappear

When my app is first loaded from a local notification, I call `didReceiveLocalNotification`, where I post a notification to run a specific function:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("popupShouldAppear", object: self)
```

Then in the view controller, I listen for that notification in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "createPopupFromNotification", name: "dayPopupShouldAppear", object: nil)
```

The above code works correctly when the app is already loaded in the background, but when initially loading the app into memory from a local notification, the final function (`createPopupFromNotification()`) fails to get called.

Based on a series of alerts I placed, it seems that `viewDidAppear()` is called *before* `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` executes `didReceiveLocalNotification`, so when the local notification is finally announced, I've lost my chance for `viewDidAppear()` to observe it.

Does this evaluation seem accurate? And if so, is there a way to delay `viewDidAppear()`?

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation

> "This method is called after state restoration has occurred but before
>   your app’s window and other UI have been presented."

Your problem seems to be the opposite you are calling the notification before it was created what shows that viewDidAppear did not yet start by the point you post the notification.

I recommend you call this function in viewDidLoad for the first time, if it run for each time you start the app, or set a flag from the delegate to you view controller to run the method for the first time if need. 
After that you can just relay in the notification to display it.

Comment: I think you're right, that the notification from the delegate is hitting a brick wall, because viewDidAppear has not been called yet and can't hear the notification. I tried calling it in viewDidLoad and that's still not happening early enough.

Comment: try not to call the notification in viewDidLoad, call the function directly after you initialise everything you need to